# Lightning inputText component readonly

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have ui:inputText component which is something like this:

```
<ui:inputText updateOn="keyup"
   keyup="{!c.keyPressController}"
   class="slds-input slds-combobox__input"
   aura:id="comboBox"
   value="{!v.searchKey}"
   placeholder="{!v.placeholder}"/>
```

Is it possible to make it readonly something like this?

```
<input type="text" class="slds-input slds-combobox__input" readonly="" value="hello" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use enhanced version of `ui:inputText` which is [lightning:input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm). It has `readonly` as attribute

```
<lightning:input name="quantity" value="1234567890"
 label="Quantity" maxlength="10" readonly="true" />
```

Same code can be written as

```
<lightning:input onchange="{!c.keyPressController}"
   class="slds-input slds-combobox__input"
   aura:id="comboBox"
   value="{!v.searchKey}"
   placeholder="{!v.placeholder}" readonly="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important for you to understand that the ui:inpiuttext and lightning:input components, when rendered, end up being broken down into html tags with specific classes and attributes.

I would encourage you to check the [Lightning Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputText.htm) whenever you ask yourself these kinds of questions. "Does this component support this?"

as pointed out by @Himanshu, the lightning:input component, does indeed support this attribute.